# How to get email.Body without html tags in C# visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, parsing, imap

Im able to get the body of the email via imap in c#, but its inclusive html tags like this...

```
<html><head></head><body><div style="font-family: Verdana;font-size: 12.0px;"><div>asd</div></div></body></html>
```

I would only want "asd" from this...

This is what I use to get it with the html tags:

```
foreach (var a in messages)
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show($"{a.Body}");

                    rec_body.AppendText( a.Body);
                }
```

Im using S22.Imap

Comment: if you want to get all the html inside body tag you can get using [this](https://www.dotnetperls.com/title-html)

Answer (score 0):

Install package from Nuget: HTML AgilityPack

You can try;

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
string s = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body").InnerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which IMAP library you are using, but if you are using [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit), you could start by more-or-less cloning MimeKit's [HtmlTextPreviewer](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/blob/master/MimeKit/Text/HtmlTextPreviewer.cs) class.

For example (untested):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using MimeKit.Text;

namespace MyNamespace {
    /// <summary>
    /// A text extractor for HTML content.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// A text extractor for HTML content.
    /// </remarks>
    public class HtmlTextExtractor
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize a new instance of the <see cref="HtmlTextExtractor"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Creates a new text extractor for HTML.
        /// </remarks>
        public HtmlTextExtractor ()
        {
        }

        static bool IsWhiteSpace (char c)
        {
            return char.IsWhiteSpace (c) || (c >= 0x200B && c <= 0x200D);
        }

        static bool Append (StringBuilder extracted, string value, ref bool lwsp)
        {
            int i;

            for (i = 0; i < value.Length; i++) {
                if (IsWhiteSpace (value[i])) {
                    if (!lwsp) {
                        extracted.Append (' ');
                        lwsp = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    extracted.Append (value[i]);
                    lwsp = false;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        sealed class HtmlTagContext
        {
            public HtmlTagContext (HtmlTagId id)
            {
                TagId = id;
            }

            public HtmlTagId TagId {
                get;
            }

            public int ListIndex {
                get; set;
            }

            public bool SuppressInnerContent {
                get; set;
            }
        }

        static void Pop (IList<HtmlTagContext> stack, HtmlTagId id)
        {
            for (int i = stack.Count; i > 0; i--) {
                if (stack[i - 1].TagId == id) {
                    stack.RemoveAt (i - 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        static bool ShouldSuppressInnerContent (HtmlTagId id)
        {
            switch (id) {
            case HtmlTagId.OL:
            case HtmlTagId.Script:
            case HtmlTagId.Style:
            case HtmlTagId.Table:
            case HtmlTagId.TBody:
            case HtmlTagId.THead:
            case HtmlTagId.TR:
            case HtmlTagId.UL:
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
            }
        }

        static bool SuppressContent (IList<HtmlTagContext> stack)
        {
            int lastIndex = stack.Count - 1;

            return lastIndex >= 0 && stack[lastIndex].SuppressInnerContent;
        }

        HtmlTagContext GetListItemContext (IList<HtmlTagContext> stack)
        {
            for (int i = stack.Count; i > 0; i--) {
                var ctx = stack[i - 1];

                if (ctx.TagId == HtmlTagId.OL || ctx.TagId == HtmlTagId.UL)
                    return ctx;
            }

            return null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Extract text from HTML input.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Gets the extracted text from HTML input.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <param name="reader">A reader for HTML text.</param>
        /// <returns>A string representing the extracted text.</returns>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">
        /// <paramref name="reader"/> is <c>null</c>.
        /// </exception>
        public string Extract (TextReader reader)
        {
            if (reader == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException (nameof (reader));

            var tokenizer = new HtmlTokenizer (reader) { IgnoreTruncatedTags = true };
            var stack = new List<HtmlTagContext> ();
            var extracted = new StringBuilder ();
            var prefix = string.Empty;
            HtmlTagContext ctx;
            HtmlAttribute attr;
            bool body = false;
            bool full = false;
            bool lwsp = true;
            HtmlToken token;

            while (!full && tokenizer.ReadNextToken (out token)) {
                switch (token.Kind) {
                case HtmlTokenKind.Tag:
                    var tag = (HtmlTagToken) token;

                    if (!tag.IsEndTag) {
                        if (body) {
                            switch (tag.Id) {
                            case HtmlTagId.Image:
                                if ((attr = tag.Attributes.FirstOrDefault (x => x.Id == HtmlAttributeId.Alt)) != null) {
                                    Append (extracted, prefix + attr.Value, ref lwsp);
                                    prefix = string.Empty;
                                }
                                break;
                            case HtmlTagId.LI:
                                if ((ctx = GetListItemContext (stack)) != null) {
                                    if (ctx.TagId == HtmlTagId.OL) {
                                        Append (extracted, $" {++ctx.ListIndex}. ", ref lwsp);
                                        prefix = string.Empty;
                                    } else {
                                        //Append (extracted, " \u2022 ", ref lwsp);
                                        prefix = " ";
                                    }
                                }
                                break;
                            case HtmlTagId.Br:
                            case HtmlTagId.P:
                                extracted.Append ('\n');
                                prefix = string.Empty;
                                lwsp = true;
                                break;
                            }

                            if (!tag.IsEmptyElement) {
                                ctx = new HtmlTagContext (tag.Id) {
                                    SuppressInnerContent = ShouldSuppressInnerContent (tag.Id)
                                };
                                stack.Add (ctx);
                            }
                        } else if (tag.Id == HtmlTagId.Body && !tag.IsEmptyElement) {
                            body = true;
                        }
                    } else if (tag.Id == HtmlTagId.Body) {
                        stack.Clear ();
                        body = false;
                    } else {
                        Pop (stack, tag.Id);
                    }
                    break;
                case HtmlTokenKind.Data:
                    if (body && !SuppressContent (stack)) {
                        var data = (HtmlDataToken) token;

                        Append (extracted, prefix + data.Data, ref lwsp);
                        prefix = string.Empty;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (lwsp && extracted.Length > 0)
                extracted.Length--;

            return extracted.ToString ();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Extract text from HTML input.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Gets the extracted text from HTML input.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <param name="reader">A reader for HTML text.</param>
        /// <returns>A string representing the extracted text.</returns>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">
        /// <paramref name="reader"/> is <c>null</c>.
        /// </exception>
        public string Extract (string input)
        {
            if (input == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException (nameof (input));

            using (var reader = new StringReader (input))
                return Extract (reader);
        }
    }
}
```

To use this class:

```
var extractor = new HtmlTextExtractor ();
var text = extractor.Extract ("<html><body>This is some text.</body></html>");
```

The class I've written above also tries to handle HTML list tags as well, so you may find that nice :)

Comment: im using s22.imap :<

Comment: S22.Imap has been abandoned for quite a few years at this point. Is this an older project? Or is it still new enough that it would be easy to switch to a different IMAP library?

Comment: For what it's worth, at least as a test, you *could* continue using S22.Imap and then try using the above code (after adding a dependency on MimeKit) to see if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code to get email body without html via IMAP.

First, please install nuget-package `ImapX`.

Second, you can try the following code to read the email body information from the gmail inbox.

```
        var client = new ImapX.ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", 993, true);
        bool t=client.Connect();
        bool m=client.Login("Username@gmail.com", "userpassword");
        var inbox= client.Folders.Inbox;
        var messages = inbox.Search("ALL", ImapX.Enums.MessageFetchMode.Full);
        foreach (var item in messages)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Body.Text);
            Console.WriteLine("*****************");
        }
```

First email in gmail website:

[image]

First email in console:

[image]